indented line after list in theorem bug
When theorem starts with a list (without triggering \par) then the line after list is indented like in the new paragraph. Is this a bug? Can it be fixed in the sources?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem} 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item text 
\end{enumerate}
% wrong 
should be unindented here
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem} 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item text 
\end{enumerate}
% correct indent
\noindent dropted indent
\end{theorem}

\end{document}


Update
As @mbert noticed the vertical space is incorrect when \noindent is used. amsthm docs offers manually create first item in the first line and other items pass to enumerate which is ok in the pdf view but nonsense in tex4ht or tagged pdf structure.
I got a correct view by adding \@noparlistfalse before \end{enumerate}
\begin{theorem}
\begin{enumerate} 
\item text 
\item text 
\csname @noparlistfalse\endcsname
\end{enumerate}
dropted indent
\end{theorem}


But still don't know is there a global solution to fix it.

I'd classify this as a feature; I bet on a race condition.

Note that the effect seems to be independent of amsathm. The indentation is sill there if amsthm is removed.

As a workaround, you can use the code from page 5 of the amsthm doc under "Theorems beginning with lists"

Also, note how even with the \noindent the vertical spacing after the list is too small. I would just start the list on a new line by adding \leavevmode after \begin{theorem}
